# How to plot more than 2 dimensions in NMDS ordination?

Tags: r, vegan

I want to plot more dimensions than 1 & 2 for a NMDS plot. How do I do this?

```
Example:
#install.packages("vegan")
library(vegan)
set.seed(2)
community_matrix=matrix(
  sample(1:100,300,replace=T),nrow=10,
  dimnames=list(paste("community",1:10,sep=""),paste("sp",1:30,sep="")))

example_NMDS=metaMDS(community_matrix, # Our community-by-species matrix
                     k=3) # Set to 3 dimensions
```

Example is from
https://jonlefcheck.net/2012/10/24/nmds-tutorial-in-r/

I read its possible to plot further dimensions by specifying ,2,3 for example. But it doesnt work

```
plot(example_NMDS,2,3). Any suggestions? Thanks! :)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the argument `choices =` , see [help page](https://rdrr.io/rforge/vegan/man/metaMDS.html) :

```
plot(example_NMDS,choices=2:3)
```

[image]